# Token deploy on mainnet, create metadata custom program error: 0x4b

Tags: web3.js, mainnet, error-handling

We are trying to deploy our token (AIDS) on mainnet: https://explorer.solana.com/address/ExCgGC6CEegjjif7yqxpcreEaarb83K8YaXzmf3PRWAZ .
When we are trying to create metadata for this token, we call method: sendAndConfirmTransaction from @solana/web3.js - library and get the following error: SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x4b .
Can You help us understand what this error means and how to deal with it?"

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create metadata using the metaplex token-metadata program, you can look at the error codes in the source.  `0x4b` corresponds to the number `75`, which is the `Removed` error code: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/965b60860afdf5c73092563b83e534411d088327/programs/token-metadata/program/src/error.rs#L314C1-L314C160

This means the instruction you're trying to use has been removed, so you'll need to update the tools to use a newer instruction.